# How to solve "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.auth"

Tags: python, google-oauth

I try to use `tensorboard --logdir=runs` to see a visualization of my training of image-recognition but it feedback with `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.auth`.

```
ubuntu 22.04
python 3.10(conda virtual environment)
```

```
(yolov5) ...@...-Legion-Y7000P-2019-PG0:~/Documents/cell_detection/yolov5$ tensorboard --logdir=runs
```

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/.../.local/bin/tensorboard", line 5, in <module>
    from tensorboard.main import run_main
  File "/home/.../.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorboard/main.py", line 27, in <module>
    from tensorboard import default
  File "/home/.../.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorboard/default.py", line 33, in <module>
    from tensorboard.plugins.audio import audio_plugin
  File "/home/.../.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorboard/plugins/audio/audio_plugin.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorboard.data import provider
  File "/home/.../.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorboard/data/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from tensorboard.data import experimental  # noqa: F401
  File "/home/.../.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorboard/data/experimental/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from tensorboard.data.experimental.experiment_from_dev import (  # noqa: F401
  File "/home/.../.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorboard/data/experimental/experiment_from_dev.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorboard.uploader import auth
  File "/home/.../.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorboard/uploader/auth.py", line 28, in <module>
    import google_auth_oauthlib.flow as auth_flows
  File "/home/.../.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google_auth_oauthlib/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .interactive import get_user_credentials
  File "/home/.../.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google_auth_oauthlib/interactive.py", line 24, in <module>
    import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
  File "/home/.../.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google_auth_oauthlib/flow.py", line 68, in <module>
    import google.auth.transport.requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.auth'
```

I have seen the answers for the problem with the same title but it seems a little different from me. It turns out that the program is using the `google.auth` from the local python's site-packeges however I've activate the conda virtual environment which named "yolov5" since I am using yolov5 to train the image-recognition model(As is displayed above).

I'm sure i've installed the google-auth using `pip`.

```
python3
Python 3.10.9 (main, Mar  8 2023, 10:47:38) [GCC 11.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import google
>>> import google.auth
>>> exit()
```

pip list

```
...
google
google_auth_oauthlib
google_auth_oauthlib-0.4.6.dist-info
...
```

```
pip show google.auth
Name: google-auth
Version: 2.16.2
Summary: Google Authentication Library
Home-page: https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python
Author: Google Cloud Platform
Author-email: googleapis-packages@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /home/.../anaconda3/envs/yolov5/lib/python3.10/site-packages
Requires: cachetools, pyasn1-modules, rsa, six
Required-by: google-auth-oauthlib, tensorboard
```

As you can see, the virtual environment's directory is `/home/.../anaconda3/envs/yolov5/lib/python3.10/site-packages`

I'm not sure whether it uses python-packeges from wrong directory. If yes, how can I correct it.
Thank you for your help.